# How Many Homeruns should I run?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a master bath framed out. Please excuse the crude drawing I did. There will be a GFI just above the double vanity. There will be lights above the vanity. There is an exhaust in the middle of the bathroom. There is a can light above the shower. The toilet room will have a single gang box with for a can light. There will be a 3 gang box just as you walk in to control the vanity lights, the exhaust and the can over the shower. I want to run a homerun to the GFI and then power from the GFI to the 3 gang and single gang box. Can I do this? Or do I need more than 1 homerun?

Thanks, in advance, for your guidance[image]

Comment: Will you have a heater in there? How much electric stuff do you want to run - do you envision having e.g. a curler and hair dryer going at once?  It's your house and your call.

Comment: And an oil diffuser, rechargeable razor, and cell phone charger..

Answer (score 2):

If I had my bathroom torn apart, I’d consider dedicated runs for all of the following:

1. Lights (don’t want the lights going out if a hairdryer trips the receptacle circuit)
2. Sink 1 receptacle
3. Sink 2 receptacle (maybe both people want to be able to run a hairdryer at the same time)
4. Toilet (some of the bidet-seat add-one basically have an on-demand water heater inside and these need a dedicated circuit)
5. Heated floor
6. Towel warmer

You don’t have to actually hook everything up right away - runs can go to boxes in likely locations and be closed off with blank cover plates. And not every home run has to go to a dedicated breaker - the sink receptacles could certainly be on one breaker until they actually need to be split.

Wire is cheap, and running it now is a lot easier than doing it after the walls are closed up. You may not want all this today, but if future-you decides you want a nice heated toilet seat someday, you’ll be glad you can do it for the price of a breaker and a receptacle instead of tearing your walls apart. You won’t regret pulling a couple extra cables.

Incidentally, this is why we harp on the value of breaker spaces so much around here. Although these are all fairly small, short-duty loads (you wouldn’t have any problem running them in a house with 100A service) they’re all individually large enough that they really can’t share a branch circuit without causing nuisance trips.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (not a code expert, just from reading other questions) you only *need* one 20A circuit for the bathroom. However, my recommendation is to install at least 2 circuits. That allows:

1. Receptacles - GFCI protected (as stated, and as required). If you have multiple receptacle locations in the bathroom, you can put them all on the same GFCI (i.e., panel to GFCI/receptacle to plain receptacle).
2. Lights - There are two practical reasons to put the lights on a separate circuit. The first is safety - if you trip the GFCI (hair dryer gets wet) or the actual breaker (hair dryer and curling iron used at the same time), you still have light. The second is upgrades - if you later decide to add a heater, you can share that with the lights (as long as total rating stays within 16A - and that is usually not a problem with LED lights together with a typical 12A rated heater). But you can't share the heater with the receptacles if it, together with the other hardwired lights, takes > 50% of the capacity of the circuit.

One more thing to consider: The light over the shower. Lights generally do *not* need to be GFCI protected. A light that is over a shower or tub needs to either be GFCI protected or be rated for use in a wet location. If you install a light that requires GFCI protection that *that* light should be connected to the receptacle circuit so that it can piggyback on the GFCI, as you can't put an actual GFCI protection device in the ceiling (and even if you could, you would not want that over a shower).

Answer (score 1):

The 2020 NEC requires:

> 210.11(C)(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits. In addition to the number of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, one or more
> 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to supply
> bathroom(s) receptacle outlet(s) required by 210.52(D) and any
> countertop and similar work surface receptacle outlets. Such circuits
> shall have no other outlets.
>
> Exception: Where the 20-ampere circuit supplies a single bathroom,
> outlets for other equipment within the same bathroom shall be
> permitted to be supplied in accordance with 210.23(A)(1) and (A)(2).

> 210.52(D) Bathrooms. In dwelling units, at least one receptacle outlet shall be installed in bathrooms within 900 mm (3 ft) of the outside
> edge of each basin. The receptacle outlet shall be located on a wall
> or partition that is adjacent to the basin or basin countertop,
> located on the countertop, or installed on the side or face of the
> basin cabinet. In no case shall the receptacle be located more than
> 300 mm (12 in.) below the countertop height. Receptacle outlet
> assemblies listed for the application shall be permitted to be
> installed in the countertop.

It appears from your description that only one circuit is required, but after all the work you have done it seems a little silly to handicap yourself. I would separate the countertop from other outlets. Also from the notes on your drawing you indicate a single gfci countertop receptacle. I think you mean duplex, which is two receptacles, so I think that would satisfy the code requirement of "each basin", but a little risky arguing interpretation.

Note(s): In Article 100 the NEC defines "outlet" to include hardwired, lighting, and receptacle connections. The "similar work surface" wording in 210.11 is new and may trip people a bit.  210.23(A)(1) and (2) restricts fastened in place cord and plug equipment to 80% of branch circuit rating and 50% of a circuit if shared with receptacles.